# Replacing desired numbers in cell

Tags: sql, oracle, case, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to replace cell if student album contains "357" numbers for "000".
The format of the column is NUMBER.
The number album can looks like this: `90432,90709,83570`, so these numbers can be "inside". 
For number `83570` I should print `80000`.

I tried like this:

```
select student.imie,
    student.nazwisko,
    case
        when student.nralbumu like '%357%' then replace(nralbumu, '%357%', '%000%')
        else student.nralbumu
    end album
from student
```

but it did not work.
I got error like:

> 00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

[image]

[image]

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Please tag your question with it. Have you tried to call the `replace` function without any '%' at all?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yea, I tried.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh pasted screenshots from DB

Comment: Is this Oracle?

Comment: As far as I know yes. I am using sql developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `REPLACE` directly since nothing will happen if the number doesn't contain 357

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(TO_CHAR(nralbumu), '357','000'))
FROM STUDENT
```

or if you don't need the result as a number

```
SELECT REPLACE(TO_CHAR(nralbumu), '357','000')
FROM STUDENT
```

Comment: Been a while since I used Oracle. Better answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this for SQL Server,

```
select student.imie,
    student.nazwisko,
    CAST(case
        when CAST(student.nralbumu AS VARCHAR) like '%357%' then replace(CAST( student.nralbumu AS VARCHAR), '357', '000')
        else CAST(student.nralbumu AS VARCHAR)
    end as NUMERIC)  album
from student
```

For Oracle, same apply. Just cast to Varchar, and back to number

So Basically if you use in Oracle, you should get the desired result.

```
SELECT   CAST(
    case
        when CAST(904329070983570 AS VARCHAR2(50)) like '%357%' then replace(CAST(904329070983570 AS VARCHAR2(50)), '357', '000')
        else CAST(904329070983570 AS VARCHAR2(50))
    end AS number(10, 0))
FROM dual;
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, please try again

Comment: In Oracle, you need to cast the column to `VARCHAR2`, and cast the whole column back to `NUMBER`.

Comment: I've updated my answer, and which left parenthesis is missing? In Oracle for VARCHAR cast, you might need to specify the length, so add `VARCHAR2(50)` or something